# My previously working node/express/mongoose server was working perfectly, and now it is emitting a strange error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, nodemon

I am fairly new to node.  I created an application based on this github code:

https://github.com/dalenguyen/rest-api-node-typescript

Yesterday, all was well and it ran just fine with the instructions from the readme.

Today, however, entering

```
npm start dev
```

results in the following:

[image]

It appears to be looking for `c:\code\todonode\server.js`, but that file doesn't exist and will not exist.  `server.ts` and thus `server.js` reside one level down in `/lib`.

This is very mysterious.

Not sure what further information might be needed.  Happy to provide anything that might help.

Why am I getting this error and how can I get my simple server back up and running?

**ADDED**:

Here is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "todonode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A TypeScript-based node REST API",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "ts-node ./lib/server.ts",
    "start": "nodemon ./dist/server.js",
    "prod": "npm run build && npm run start"
  },
  "author": "Nick Hodges",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I should add that rebooting my machine didn't help.

Comment: I'm also fairly new to node. Have you been running `npm start dev` from the same directory every time?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  Yes, I have.  It doesn't work if I run from ./lib either.

Comment: @NickHodges - please post your package.json

Comment: @NickHodges - There is something not visible to us, but one thing - if you want to run `dev`, you have to use `npm run dev`

Comment: @libik Wow -- I feel foolish.  `npm run dev` made it work.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The server.js file will be produced in the `./dist` folder when you run `npm run-script build` to build the application.

The 'main' field in your package.json contains the main entry point for your program. You have it listed as `server.js`, so it is looking in your root folder for the file.

You will need to change this from:

```
"main": "server.js"
```

to:

```
"main": "./dist/server.js"
```

in your package.json.